# clojure equivalent for ruby's gsub

Tags: regex, clojure

How do i do this in clojure

```
"text".gsub(/(\d)([ap]m|oclock)\b/, '\1 \2')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Java's [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. The call would look like:

```
(.replaceAll "text" "(\\d)([ap]m|oclock)\\b" "$1 $2")
```

Note that this will return a new string (like `gsub` (without the bang) would in ruby). There is no equivalent for `gsub!` in Clojure as Java/Clojure string are immutable.

Comment: yea sorry i meant gsub. Thanks this makes sense.

Comment: Please fix the link to [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: @CMPITG Just did. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 25):

To add to Isaac's answer, this is how you would use `clojure.string/replace` in this particular occasion:

```
user> (str/replace "9oclock"
                   #"(\d)([ap]m|oclock)\b"
                   (fn [[_ a b]] (str a " " b)))
                   ;    ^- note the destructuring of the match result
                   ;^- using an fn to produce the replacement 
"9 oclock"
```

To add to sepp2k's answer, this is how you can take advantage of Clojure's regex literals while using the `"$1 $2"` gimmick (arguably simpler than a separate `fn` in this case):

```
user> (.replaceAll (re-matcher #"(\d)([ap]m|oclock)\b" "9oclock")
                   ;           ^- note the regex literal
                   "$1 $2")
"9 oclock"
```

Comment: Nice use of destructing hadnt thought of that. But i need a more generic solution so i am going with the second option.

Comment: Actually I would have thought the function-based solution is the more "generic", at the cost of a certain number of extra keystrokes. (Imagine replacing the first groups with the string representation of its length: `"asdf"` -> `"4"`; not really doable with `$1` & Co. On the other hand, anything you can do with `$1` can also be done with a function.) No argument about the simpler option being possibly more suitable here, though.

Comment: Thanks for providing an example! I was short on time, but probably should've made my answer clearer. I, too, like the generality and power of the `replace` function, though can see the appeal of the `.replaceAll` method's simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

That would be `replace` in the clojure.string namespace. You can find it [here](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.string-api.html#clojure.string/replace).

Use it like so:

```
(ns rep
  (:use [clojure.string :only (replace)]))
(replace "this is a testing string testing testing one two three" ;; string
         "testing" ;; match
         "Mort") ;; replacement
```

`replace` is awesome because the match and replacement can also be string/string or char/char, or you could even do regex pattern/function of the match or string.

Comment: Second argument cannot be a '\1 \2' ( which is one match substring 1and match substring 2 ). That is what i am looking for.

Comment: Though `.replaceAll` may be more isomorphic to `gsub`, `replace` can do what you want: if you use a pattern (like in your example) you could use a function to process the result of the regex pattern, and do whatever you wanted. It's actually quite a bit more powerful than `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure contrib now has [re-gsub](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.str-utils/re-gsub) as a part of str-utils:

```
user=> (def examplestr (str "jack and jill" \newline "went up the hill"))
#'user/examplestr

user=> (println examplestr)
jack and jill
went up the hill
nil

user=> (println (re-gsub #"\n" " " examplestr))
jack and jill went up the hill
nil
```

Comment: That link is now dead. Did it get renamed or removed?